# django postgresql tests.py RuntimeWarning error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing

I have a Django app that adds and displays stuff to my postgresql database online at elephantsql.com. My project file setup looks like this:

```
website/
    website/
    music/
    playlist/  
            __pycache__/
            migrations/
            static/
            templates/
            __init__.py
            admin.py
            apps.py
            models.py
            tests.py
            urls.py
            views.py
    .coverage
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
```

My project works right now where when I run the server and go to /playlist/ it displays stuff correctly and connects to my postgresql database fine.

My settings.py DATABASES object looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'kxvmghva',
        'USER': 'kxvmghva',
        'PASSWORD': '--an actual password---',
        'HOST': 'raja.db.elephantsql.com', 
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to write test cases in my playlist/tests.py file, but when I try to run these tests I'm getting errors.

my testing file I'm trying to run /playlist/tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import plays
from django.utils import timezone


class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print("setup")
        #Animal.objects.create(name="lion", sound="roar")
        #Animal.objects.create(name="cat", sound="meow")

    def test_animals_can_speak(self):
        """Animals that can speak are correctly identified"""
        print("test")
        #lion = Animal.objects.get(name="lion")
        #cat = Animal.objects.get(name="cat")
        #self.assertEqual(lion.speak(), 'The lion says "roar"')
        #self.assertEqual(cat.speak(), 'The cat says "meow"')
```

When I run the command "python manage.py test playlist" I get these errors:

```
C:\Users\marti\Documents\kexp\website>python manage.py test playlist
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py:267: RuntimeWarning: Normally Django will use a connection to the 'postgres' database to avoid running initialization queries against the production database when it's not needed (for example, when running tests). Django was unable to create a connection to the 'postgres' database and will use the default database instead.
  RuntimeWarning
Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_kxvmghva', or 'no' to cancel:
```

if I type 'yes' it leads to this error:

```
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error recreating the test database: database "test_kxvmghva" does not exist
```

I've been trying to solve this error by searching it online and have tried stuff like giving my user 'kxvmghva' CREATEDB permissions as well as running this line in my elephantsql db:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO kxvmghva;

But I'm still getting these errors when trying to run the tests.py file for my playlist/ app. This is my first time setting up test cases for a postgresql database in django and I would really appreciate any help or guidance. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can try: 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'

Comment: `python manage.py test playlist --keepdb` at least gets rid of the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the plan you are using for database is free/shared, in case which you do not have rights to create additional databases.

This is not a Django problem but restrictions of the service you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56318786/4470542), [ElephantSQL](https://www.elephantsql.com/) free tier (I suppose you're using this one) is shared. In that server, they have several DBs, so you have access to one and can't create another one.

I've tried to create an [instance just for tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#test), but it also fails because "On PostgreSQL, USER will also need read access to the built-in postgres database." (from [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)).

So, my solution, and understand it is not the best of practices (because you'll have a different environment for testing) is replacing the engine for testing:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    },
}
```

This configuration works because (from the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)):

> When using SQLite, the tests will use an in-memory database by default (i.e., the database will be created in memory, bypassing the filesystem entirely!)

Two notes:

- Use GitHub actions or a similar solution to test against PostgreSQL in each commit (this way, you reduce the danger of using different test and prod databases)
- The easiest way to have a different setting config is to use separate files. I follow the logic in [cookiecutter-django](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django/tree/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/config)